# Mockito Spy Test

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am using Mockito to write tests for code. However I am stuck at following scenario - 
Class A has 2 methods, method1() and method2(). I tried using ArgumentCaptor to catch values sent to method2(). But, since I am using @Spy, I cannot use Matchers.

How do I test method1()?

```
class A{
    B b;
    method1(arg1, arg2){
       //some logic
       method2(arg1, arg2, ....argN);
    }

   method2(arg1, arg2,....argN){
       //some logic
       b.method3(arg1, arg2...);
   }
}
```

How to verify method2 receives same argument values?
Following is the test class I wrote:

```
Class TestA{

@Mock
B b;

@Spy
@InjectMocks   //required else b is null
A a = new A();

@Test
public void testMethod1(){

 a.method1(arg1, arg2);

  //How to verify method2 receives same argument values (arg1, arg2)????
  //verify(a, times(1)).method2(.......);   
}
```

}

Comment: I added a coded example as an answer based on your discussion with David

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was intrigued by this post and the comments left by @David so I decided to code a working example for those who follow like me

```
/*
 * class to test
 */
public class A {

    public void methodA(String str) {
        this.methodB(str);
    }

    protected void methodB(String str) {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

We want to assert that the value being passed into methodB() is what we expect. Reading up on the [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) led me to discover the equivalent [Captor Annotation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Captor.html)

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MultipleMethodCallTest {

    @Spy
    A a = new A();

    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> captor;

    @Test
    public void captureSecondMethodCallArgument() throws Exception {

        // EXPECTED

        String greeting = "hello world";

        // PERFORM TEST

        a.methodA(greeting);

        // ASSERT

        verify(a).methodB(captor.capture());

        assertEquals(greeting, captor.getValue());
    }
}
```

This example was tested with

- mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
- junit-4.8.2.jar

Comment: See @Dawood ibn Kareem's answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292649/3477577 This is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cant, you have to verify it by B's method3 call. If your args to method2 have no effect on method3, theses args could be useless at all?!

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the sample code to reflect the args being passed to method3 as well. Yes I could verify the method 3 call. I am wondering, if I am writing the test correctly? Because I haven't seen examples with Spy and InjectMocks conjunction. Is there a better approach to write the test case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use matchers with spies; this works just fine.  I don't know why you thought that you couldn't.

I took your source code and edited it to make it compile.  I then added a call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` - you need this to create the spy and the mock, and to inject the mock (unless you use the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, which does the `initMocks` for you).  I put the `verify` of the call to `method2` back in.  This worked fine.

So, contrary to Omnaest's answer, you don't need to use B's `method3` to verify this.  I suspect that your only problem was that you had forgotten the `initMocks`.

Good luck with this, and feel free to post again if you need any more help.

Comment: Yeah you're right, CGLIB does really extend the class, so it can override method2 and so it can capture even internal calls. So basically Mockito can do it in thas exactly case. Nevertheless I never saw this in real applications, since internal methods are most of the case declared as private. So you're forced to declare internal methods at least with package or protected. I don't know if that's a good approach at all. But still the question seems to point at mockito's abilities, so definitely yes, it works.

Comment: True, I'm not saying that this is a good approach.  But when the provided source code is stripped down to the point where we can't tell what the OP is trying to do, it was the best answer I could provide.  There may be a deeper question here, along the lines of "how can I best unit test a class that does XYZ" - but unfortunately that question hasn't been asked, so we can't actually see which testing problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I was using RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation and when I tried 'verify(a, times(1)).method2(.......)',the  exception is _verify() should be used with mock objects_ . And I do have the question: 'Is this the best way to test this scenario'? I am new to Mockito and still learning by experimenting.

Comment: OK, I just tried this again, using the `MockitoJUnitRunner` instead of calling `initMocks` directly.  The test still passes for me; there's no exception.  I used Mockito 1.9.0-RC1, but I don't believe that anything in this area has changed between RC1 and the official release of 1.9.0.  Which version of Mockito do you have, so that I can keep trying to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @DavidWallace - Yes I am using the latest Mockito version 1.9.0 . I do not have the exact error message I got earlier. Anyways it's working now. thanks.

Comment: OK, I'll stop trying to reproduce your error. In answer to your question "is this the best way to test this scenario", it's kind of hard to tell, since we don't know that the scenario is.  My guess is probably not; verifying spies often points to poorly designed tests, but this is all a bit out-of-context.  What tests you write should always depend on more on the _behaviour_ that you're trying to test, than on the _mechanism_ that you've used to implement that behaviour. I would advise you to post a separate question - describe the behaviour that you're trying to test, and ask for suggestions.

Comment: @aces you should accept this as the correct answer. I almost didn't read on after seeing this as the currently accepted answer with a higher ranking than this one